# Linq to XML, select query with where condition

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This is my XML content:

```
<ListEnginsMesures>
    <EnginsESC>
      <NomValide>Engin_inconnu</NomValide>
      <NomEquivalents>
        <NomEquivalent>Engin inconnu</NomEquivalent>
        <NomEquivalent>Engininconnu</NomEquivalent>
      </NomEquivalents>
    </EnginsESC>
    <EnginsESC>
      <NomValide>DRSC_6150</NomValide>
      <NomEquivalents>
        <NomEquivalent>DRSC 6150</NomEquivalent>
        <NomEquivalent>DRSC6150</NomEquivalent>
        <NomEquivalent>DRSC6.150</NomEquivalent>
        <NomEquivalent>DRSC_6.150</NomEquivalent>
      </NomEquivalents>
    </EnginsESC>
<ListEnginsMesures>
```

I want to select value of 'NomValide' when i have 'NomEquivalent'.

For example :

(select 'NomValide' where 'NomEquivalent' = "Engin inconnu") will return Engin_inconnu.

(select 'NomValide' where 'NomEquivalent' = "DRSC_6.150") will return DRSC_6150.

HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THIS ONE ?

THANKS IN ADVANCE..

Comment: It's always a good idea to start with what you've got so far - ideally in a short but complete program. Then explain what's going wrong. I suspect you'll want a query for `EnginsESC` elements with a `Where` clause which checks whether any of the `NomEquivalent` descendants has the value you're looking for.

Comment: How i wish Jon was my first commentor. That being said..u want something like `select Nom Valide from ListEngins where NomEquivalents.Any()`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, the problem is SOLVED. THANKS AGAIN...

Answer (score 2):

If you expect only one result then the following should work:

```
string xml=@"<ListEnginsMesures>
    <EnginsESC>
      <NomValide>Engin_inconnu</NomValide>
      <NomEquivalents>
        <NomEquivalent>Engin inconnu</NomEquivalent>
        <NomEquivalent>Engininconnu</NomEquivalent>
      </NomEquivalents>
    </EnginsESC>
    <EnginsESC>
      <NomValide>DRSC_6150</NomValide>
      <NomEquivalents>
        <NomEquivalent>DRSC 6150</NomEquivalent>
        <NomEquivalent>DRSC6150</NomEquivalent>
        <NomEquivalent>DRSC6.150</NomEquivalent>
        <NomEquivalent>DRSC_6.150</NomEquivalent>
      </NomEquivalents>
    </EnginsESC>
</ListEnginsMesures>";

var xe = XElement.Parse(xml);
var result = xe.Elements("EnginsESC")
    .Where
    (
        x=>
        x.Element("NomEquivalents")
            .Elements("NomEquivalent")
            .Any(n=>(string)n=="Engin inconnu")
    )
    .Select(x=>(string)x.Element("NomValide"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you expect more than one results:

```
var results = xe.Elements("EnginsESC")
    .Where
    (
        x=>
        x.Element("NomEquivalents")
            .Elements("NomEquivalent")
            .Any(n=>(string)n=="Engin inconnu")
    )
    .Select(x=>(string)x.Element("NomValide"));
```

Comment: THANKS FOR THE ANSWER, PERFECT THIS ANSWER.THANK YOUU VERRYYY MUUUCH. WHAT A REACTIVITY..